# Get rid of error on guest checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkout, spree

I have removed the address and delivery states from my spree application and set it to this:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do

  checkout_flow do
    go_to_state :payment, :if => lambda { |order| order.payment_required? }
    go_to_state :confirm, :if => lambda { |order| order.confirmation_required? }
    go_to_state :complete
    remove_transition :from => :payment, :to => :confirm
  end

end
```

I remove it because currently my employer only want to do in-store pickups.
Now this works great if the user is logged in then I get no errors but if I try to do guest checkout (which my employer wants) I get this error:

```
2 errors prohibited this record from being saved:

There were problems with the following fields:

    State is invalid
    State is invalid
```

Now I am new to spree so please forgive me if this is a stupid question, but what in the address and/or delivery would mess up that the guest checkout will not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was told by Creator of Spree that it was a devise_auth error that was fixed but not commited to stable branch of git repo